# How to get pixel/offsite conversion stats from Facebook's ads API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm using the Python SDK for the Facebook ads api to get ad performance reports for Facebook ad campaigns.

The problem is that I can't find a way to get the number of pixel/offsite conversions, and I'm not even sure about where to look for it (campaign, adset, adgroup,ad creative..)
When I get stats on any level it is not included under "actions".

I looked through the documentation and only saw explanations for creating and defining pixels.

I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

Until now I was using the "get_stats" method and I didn't find this information there.

After posting here I looked at each level's object's methods and saw that there are a few different methods for getting ad stats:

One of the options is "get_conversion_stats", which is available at the account and adgroup levels. Additionally, from the account level it is possible to get the adset and adgroup's conversion data using "get_ad_campaign_conversion_stats" and "get_ad_group_conversion_stats".
(According to the "old" facebook ads terminology, where campaign is today's adset)

There might be more ways to get it, and I'd appreciate anyone telling me about the, but for now I'll be using these methods.

Hope this helps whoever encounters this issue next.

Answer (score 3):

If your pixel track conversions, you'll find them under the action response field if you use the field 'actions_group_by' set to 'action_type'. They come in the form of "offsite_conversion".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ad reports endpoints to retrieve action counts and spend at different levels (time based and or by object, including ad): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can get these information from actions field of insight of each adset or ads.
For example: here is my command in facebook's developer site:
[image]

[image]